# Is the following number set compact?

Tags: real-analysis, compactness

I'm trying to find if the following number set is compact?

S=  $\{(-1)^n+\frac{1}{n}_{n\in \mathbb{N}}\}$

I know for it to be compact it must be closed, and bounded.

Here the number set is bounded between 1.5 and -1.

Now the part if the number set is closed, but i'm getting stuck since.

Let $X$ be a metric space and $A \subset X$. $A$ is closed in $X$ iff any sequence in $A$, which converges in $X$, converges in $A$. Now here since the number set converges towards 0, as $2n \rightarrow \infty$ Since only the even numbers converge to 0, but the number set converges towards $-1$ as 2n +1 $\rightarrow \infty$ Since the odd terms only converge to -1. I know it might not be the right idea, but any help would be appreciated.

So since it's bounded, and it converges to 0, -1, would this number set be compact?

Comment: For large even $n$ you have $(-1)^n+\frac1n \approx +1$ rather than $0$. So there are two accumulation points: $\pm 1$.  Are they in $S$?

Comment: Oh I see know that as n $\rightarrow \infty$ it converges to 1....

Comment: $+1$ is not in $S$

Comment: Yeah i get it now, since the number will get only infinitely close to 1 but never get there, right?

Comment: "Infinitely close"  figuratively but not literally.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your set is not compact because it is not closed.

Note that the limit points $1$ and $-1$ do not belong to your set, therefore it is not closed.

Comment: 1 would not be in the set, since the number set converges to 1, but never really reaches there correct?

Comment: Correct, $1$ is not an element of the set.

Comment: Now just a random question, here the supremum would be 1.5, which is in the set, thus it's also considered as the maximum as well right?

Comment: Good point. Yes the supremum  is attained and it is also your maximum.